# Are there different Android contexts?

Tags: android, android-context

I thought that Android context work as a singleton object which you access from differents ways.

- Activities: like "this"
- Methods: getContext() or getApplicationContext()
- and more...

However, in my project, I've created a simple Spinner using a simple ArrayAdapter in an nested AsyncTask (onPostExecuteMethod) in my MainActivity  and I saw that it works different using **getApplicationContext()** and **MainActivity.this**.

1. Text white with -> getApplicationContext()
2. Text dark with -> MainActivity.this

Can you explain me that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Context` obtained from `getApplicationContext()` does not implement everything an `Activity` does, specially things related to UI, Themes, ...

The most complete explanation I have seen so far : [Context,
What Context?](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

Basically :

- Use the Activity for everything related to the UI.
- Use the application context for anything that can live longer than the `Activity`.

Answer (score 3):

Every Context are related to the application context, each activity has it's own sub-context that will live with the activity (and will be destroyed with the activity).

In your example, you have different rendering depending on the context you use because Activities use [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) if they have been assigned a theme (programmatically or in manifest).

You probably have a dark theme in your application but a light theme for the activity.